# How can I create a record with a nested/embedded record in Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How can I create a nested/embedded model when creating a record with Ember Data? Specifically, I want to create a post model with a nested/embedded model author. The following code gives me the error:

*Error while processing route: index Assertion Failed: You cannot add a 'undefined' record to the 'post.author'. You can only add a 'author' record to this relationship. Error: Assertion Failed: You cannot add a 'undefined' record to the 'post.author'. You can only add a 'author' record to this relationship.*

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('post', {
      title: 'My first post',
      body: 'lorem ipsum ...',
      author: {
        fullname: 'John Doe',
        dob: '12/25/1999'
      }
    });
  }
});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string'),
  author: DS.belongsTo('author')
});

App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
  fullname: DS.attr('string'),
  dob: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Any ideas on how to do this? I also created a demo on JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/depiyugixo/edit?html,js,console,output

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relationships need to be assigned to instantiated models, plain objects won't work.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.createRecord('post', {
      title: 'My first post',
      body: 'lorem ipsum ...',
      author: this.store.createRecord('author', {
        fullname: 'John Doe',
        dob: '12/25/1999'
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Note that in order to have `author` show up in your POST request you'll need `DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin`, as detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45393935/470472.